# crystal report Remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula missing dll

Tags: dll, crystal-reports-8.5

I am getting error: "Remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula" while trying to view the report. As I understand some dlls are missing, because on some xp machines I am not getting any errors, on some I do.
My question would be how do find out which dll's I am missing? Which ones crystal are using for viewing? My formula is very simple for the section:

```
iif ({PRODUCT.PRODUCTCODE}="LT",true,false);
```

If add a dll file with the same name in windows folder, I mean replace, do I have to register it anyway?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if you want display "to date" formula field on crystal report then this type of error is occured. So we need to write the following code in your source code file.

```
 rpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["to_date"].Text = "'" + txt_to_date.Text.Trim() + "'";  crystalReportViewer_month_report.ReportSource = rpt;
```

We need to enclose the `txt_to_date.Text.Trim()` in between single quote " ' ".